# How to set/find ftp username , password , connection type in linux

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I have set up wordpress in my linux server and when i try to install addons to wordpress it requests ftp username, password, connection type and connection type FTP FTPS. I managed to install ftp in my linux server using apt-get install ftp. But how do i find the other information ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your username and password will be the username and password you use to login to your linux mahine. You will probably be using FTP connection type, but should look at using FTPS as this is secure and doesn't send your username/password over the wire in clear text.
With that you should look at using a user account without a lot of privileges if using FTP to minimize what a hacker could do if your credentials were sniffed on the wire.

Comment: thanx for your reply. how do i use FTPS ? can i just install FTPS using apt-get install ftps ??

Comment: There is a good article on ubuntu forums (see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=79588 ) that should help, particularly review C-Advanced Tricks as this covers setting up FTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Recommanded:

If you are using linux:

```
//Set www to 777
# chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
// Change the owner to apache (centos)
# chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
// Change the owner to apache (ubuntu)
# chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
// Restart httpd
# systemctl restart httpd
```

Not recommanded but works:

Add this line in wp-config.php

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Comment: Setting `www` to 777 seems like a security vulnerability.